# Excel: find row in a table by condition

Tags: excel, formula

I have two tables with same column names, but different data.

Table1:

```
   A B C D
1  3 4 5 OK
2  6 7 8
3  9 8 7
```

Table2:

```
   A B C D
1  9 8 7
2  1 2 8
3  3 4 5
```

I want to write formula in `D` of `Table2`, which would copy `D`-column values by row values from `Table1`. (I want to find same row in other table and set `D`-column value for it).
I could use `SUMIFS(Table1!$D:$D, Table1!$A:$A, "="&A1, Table1!$B:$B, "="&B1, Table1!$C:$C, "="&C1)`, but all the rows are unique and I have string value in `$D:$D` - I don't need `SUM` exactly, I need only one string value.

Is there any function to find column value by row condition?

The result I want:

```
   A B C D
1  9 8 7
2  1 2 8
3  3 4 5 OK
```

Comment: you can use make an array of table-1 and the perform vlookup/match+index on first three cols of table-2 to return value in col. D there

Comment: Would this work for you `=LOOKUP(2,1/((Table1!$A:$A=A1)*(Table1!$B:$B=B1)*(Table1!$C:$C=C1)),Table1!$D:$D)`